# How to put conditions using the decimals in calculations?

Tags: r, plot, raster

Having two rasters (values are floats with 5 decimals) with the same dimensions.
The code given below makes one file out of two rasters r and r1. If r is bigger,put blue ,otherwise put red.

This code worked well but I was asked to add another condition. 
How this code works:

If r is 0.229 and r1 is 0.228 then r is bigger(notice third decimal).
what I need  is to specify the first two decimals for example:

```
     r= 0.228   r1=0.224   put  yellow colour(they are rather similar)
     r= 0.238   r1=0.224   put  blue colour(r is bigger)
     r= 0.128   r1=0.224   put  red colour(r is lower)
```

1- to read the first file r

```
     conn <- file("C:\\corr.bin","rb")
     corr<- readBin(conn, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

2- to read the second file r1:

```
    conne <- file("C:\\cor06.bin","rb")
    over<-readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
```

calculate:

```
 r <-raster(t(matrix((data=corr), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))
 r1 <- raster(t(matrix((data=over), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))
 m <- r > r1 #Compare the two rasters
 image( m , col = c("blue" , "red" ) )
```

Comment: What about if r is 0.232 and r1 is 0.229? Do you put yellow or do you put blue? How about if the difference is < 0.01?

Comment: Are you sure that is sensible? Your data doesn't look categorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You now want to create colours based on if one is greater than the other, or the difference between the two is less than 0.01. You can do this simply like this:

```
# Example data
r <- raster( system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster") )
r1 <- r * rnorm( ncell(r))

# Make new raster
m <- raster( r )

# 3 = Yellow , 2 = "Red" , 1 = "Blue"
values( m ) <- ifelse( abs( r[] - r1[] ) <= 0.01 , 3 , ifelse( r[] > r1[] , 1 , 2 ) )
image( m , col = c( 1 = "Blue" , 2 = "Red" , 3 = "Yellow" ) )
```

You can use the `value = "colour"` style of argument in `col` ensuring colours are assigned to the right levels.
[image]

Comment: I'm just curious, is `values` a function in a specific package...?

Comment: Yes it is (part of `raster`). It is because more than one part of the raster object may be changed when altering values. Accessing the values slot directly is not advised, and values provides a convenient safe wrapper for that purpose.

Comment: @joran see `raster:::setValues` - values is just shorthand call for the method

Comment: My values are floats and do not really know how many decimals?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are 0.000000001 or 0.111111 or 0.111, as long as they are not say 10.111 and 100.00000003. The important part is what is before the decimal place? Are they all one digit, then decimal place then however many digits?

Comment: Well, I was actually asking what package it was in (I couldn't find it in **raster** but clearly I'm just not awake yet). Regardless, I was just going to suggest that `trunc(x * 100) / 100)` to get only two digits.

Comment: @joran Oh yes, this is much better - no conversion. You are obviously more clear headed than I! Do you mind if I edit with this suggestion?

Comment: @ZadSim The function is `trunc` not `truncate`, as I said in my comment.

Comment: @ZadSim It simply says, `set the values of raster m to be:`  
`if( the first two decimal places of raster r1 and r are the same ) then '3'`  
`elseif( raster r is bigger than r1 then '1' )`  
`else set value to 2`  

Then when we plot we say that 3 equals yellow, 2 equals red and 1 equals blue. Does that make sense to you. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: @zad. see code edit. and i suggest you delete your new question as it is now a direct duplicate.

Comment: @ZadSim Well I was assuming that R would treat the 1,2 and 3 as factor levels, and that they would be assigned the colour in numeric order. I could have been wrong. It sounds like you think so? The best way to ensure the colours is to do what I did in the code and do for example `3 = "yellow"`. Has this solved the problem?

Comment: @ZadSim Sorry, surround the numbers with quotes as well, e.g. `c( "1" = "Blue" , "2" = "Red" , "3" = "Yellow" )`.

Comment: @ZadSim see code edit. You want the abs command for that. It take the absolute value of it's result, so -3 would become 3, whilst 3 remains 3.