# How to represent certain values in a file as we want?

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster file(1440*720 rows) contains values of 1 ,2 , and 3.
when I plot  the file , I got a map of three colors but I do not know which is which.
How can I put those colors as as I want :

```
   1=red
   2=blue
   3=green
```

code:

```
pvm <- file("C:\\User_sm-das.bin","rb")
cor1<- readBin(pvm, numeric(), size=4,  n=1440*720, signed=TRUE)
r <-raster(t(matrix((data=cor1), ncol=720, nrow=1440)))
image(r)
```

Comment: come one ! runif(1000) contains values of 1,2,3?!! even R experts can't understand what do you mean here!

Comment: You can use my reproducible example ..it contains only 1,2, or 3...

Comment: Us @agstudy 's example for how to get a matrix with only 1, 2 or 3, but try to change the code so you have the right number of values for the size of your raster (e.g. 1440*720.) I'd just like to see you are trying some skills beyond copy/paste. You may have to check the help pages, to see what the arguments mean. In R arguments can be named e.g. `matrix( data = runif(1000) )` or they may be matched by position, so `matrix( runif(1000))` gives the same result. Check the help page for `sample` and `matrix`) and see if you can make a matrix of 1440*720 consisting of only 1,2 or 3 in 1440 rows.

Comment: I promise to upvote you if you do this, and I will upvote each of your questions which you to change to use small reproducible examples, just like your question on hexbin package colouring, which was a perfect example of how you should ask a question! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `image.plot` from `fields` which add a legend to the image. Here an example :

First I generate some data :

```
set.seed(1234)
x<- 1:5; y<- 1:5
z<- matrix(sample(c(1,2,3),25,rep=TRUE),ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
```

Then using `fields` you can have this , it uses the usual `image` parameters adding a legend.

```
# fields 
library(fields)
image.plot(x,y,z,col = c("blue" , "red" ,"yellow"),
           interpolate=TRUE)
```

[image]

Note that if you want to convert your raster matrix to a matrix of color you can do something like this :

```
## raster 
r <- raster(ncol=5, nrow=5)
values(r) <- z
mm <- matrix(c("blue" , "red" ,"yellow")[values(r)],
             ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)

     [,1]     [,2]   [,3]   [,4]     [,5]    
[1,] "blue"   "red"  "red"  "red"    "yellow"
[2,] "red"    "blue" "blue" "red"    "red"   
[3,] "yellow" "red"  "blue" "yellow" "blue"  
[4,] "yellow" "blue" "blue" "blue"   "blue"  
[5,] "blue"   "blue" "blue" "blue"   "blue"
```

The problem with `image` you can't plot a mtrix of colors you need to have numeric values. But you can use `grid.raster` from `grid` package:

```
library(grid)
grid.raster(mm,interpolate=FALSE)
```

**EDIT**

To fix a legend manually you can play with  `axis.args` argument of `plot.image`

```
   ## fields 
image.plot(x,y,z,
           col = c("red" , "green" ,"blue"),
           axis.args=list( at=0:3, labels=0:3 ))
```

Comment: It is not the same question here! you ask for "I do not know which is which" ...I understand you need a legend. To insure that red is 1, you need to fix a legend manually , you need to play with `iamge.plot` parameters or to use `grid.raster` with a matrix of color... I hope it is clear.

Comment: @ZadSim you asked this as an addendum to your previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15619346/1478381). Why are you asking it again? I have re-edited my answer to your question with amendments (agan!) to answer you.

Comment: But m has `x`and `y` axes and values at each data location - `z`. Think of x as longitude, y as latitude and z as the data point at that location. READ the documentation!

Comment: @ZadSim That is simply not true. image( m , col = c( "1" = "blue" , "2" = "red" , "3" = "yellow" ) ) and image( m , col = c( "1" = "red" , "2" = "blue" , "3" = "yellow" ) ) give entirely different images (i.e. red and blue are swapped around.

Comment: @ZadSim Sorry, my fault - changing the order of the colours changes the plot. Changing the order of the value will not do anything, you are correct. R will colour the variables according to the factor level. So even if a two appears first in your data, it will colour anything labelled 1 with the first colour. So if the start of your matrix is 3,1,1,2 you and you  specify the colours c("red","yellow","blue"), the first colour plotted will be blue. You should learn how to add a legend to your plots to show this though.

Comment: @ZadSim How many times have we said the same thing - provide a small reproducible example. You have only eer made one attempt to make your example reproducible. We cannot complete the command `pvm <- file("C:\\User_sm-das.bin","rb")`, therefore it is not reproducible. You should replace this line with some dummy data we can use in R to recreate your problem ,e.g. like `m <- matrix(runif(1000),nrow=10); r <- raster(m)`. If you did this I would give you an upvote. I do not want to discourage you, but you really need to read the FAQ and about and learn how to get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 0):

With RaterLayer 'r', you can do plot(r) to get a plot and legend